# How to get ID of EMR matching specific name only with boto3

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-emr

How do I get a list of AWS EMR cluster IDs matching a specific name with boto3?

I have this code here:

```
import sys
import time

import boto3


client = boto3.client("emr")
cluster_name = 'Adhoc-CSDP-EMR'
response = client.list_clusters(
    ClusterStates=[
    'RUNNING', 'WAITING'
    ]
)
for cluster in response['Clusters']:
    print(cluster['Name'])
    print(cluster['Id'])
```

That will print all clusters in the running or waiting state.  How do I filter the results that match cluster_name?

Answer (score 1):

Umm, why can't we do something like this?

```
matching_cluster_ids = list()

for cluster in response['Clusters']:
    if cluster_name == cluster['Name']:
        matching_cluster_ids.append(cluster['Id'])
```

Later you can execute a `describe_cluster()` (or any other operation) on any of the matching cluster_ids if you want.